# Subsetting a rectengular matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 5139 x 30 matrix and wonder how can I split it into 39 subsets in a for loop condition in MATLAB.

My goal:
The first subset will have 132 rows & all columns. The second subset has 132+132 rows & all columns, and the third subset has 132+132+132 rows & all columns.

This will go on until 5139 rows is reached.

Thank you.

Comment: Since `39` does not evenly divide `5139*30` the right answer might be *with difficulty*.  You should explain more, best if that further explanation includes your own code to show us how far you've got, and exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for the response.....the final subset don’t need to be the same size of other subsets....i need a sunset of either 39 or or 40 subsets. Unfortunately nothing devices evenly with 5139*30. Hence, the final subset can have a different size. How can I manage that?

Comment: Think like this. First subset having 132 rows all columns. The second subset having 132+132 rows all columns, the third subset having 133+132+132 rows all columns. This will go on until 5139 rows is reached. This is how I need this actually.

Comment: Edit your question, don't put useful material in comments where a lot of people won't read it.  And show us your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment, I believe that the code following could achieve your goal:

```
%%generate the data and find the boundary of the data
Data=rand(5139,30);
[m,~]=size(Data);

%%calculate the index of every subset and split the data
L=1;
R=132;
Subset=cell(39,1);
for ii=1:39
  Subset{ii}=Data(L:R,:);
  R=R+132;
  R=min(R,m);
end
```

**Edit:** thanks @CrisLuengo 's useful comment which adds the readability of the code.

Comment: `R(R>m)=m` is an interesting way to do this. But I would suggest `R=min(R,m)` for readability.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Agreed, thanks for reminding me about this. I'm pretty sure that the GRE test takes some programming time and skills away from me. :-(  [Anyway, I'm just joking.]

Comment: Not at all. Good luck with the test!